# Point Sub Domain from Centos 6 Server to godaddy hosting

Tags: centos6, subdomain

I have domain which hosted at centos 6 server and I want to point one sub domain to another server (Godaddy)
Should I install DNS server?

Or its enough to edit resolv.conf
I tried to add the IP Address of my Godaddy hosting to the resolv.conf
and tried to edit httpd.conf but did not find anything to change their

Any advice!

Comment: If your domain is working, you already *have* a DNS server somewhere. You likely need to add records there, not install a second DNS server.

Comment: @ceejayoz sure, I already host the domain in Godaddy... but the sub domain created in centos server because the domain point to it 
I tried to add record in /etc/hosts but not working also

Comment: GoDaddy offers three services relevant here: domain registration, DNS, and web hosting. It's possible you're using GoDaddy's DNS; it's possible your server is managing it instead. If you give us the domain, we might be able to give more advice.